# How to disable Create new revision option in a node programmatically

Tags: nodes

I am trying to disable the 'Create new revision option' in each existing nodes programmatically.
I tried with below codes but it was not working.

```
$results = db_select('node', 'n')
->fields('n', array('nid','vid'))
->execute();
foreach ($results as $result) {
$node = node_load($result->nid);
// Disabling the Create new revision option
$node->revision = FALSE;
node_save($node);
}
```

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: are you using this module? https://drupal.org/project/revisioning

Comment: Do you want to remove revision option from node update form ?

Comment: @shrish I am not using this module.

Comment: @Anil I don't want to remove this option. I need to disable this option programmatically to some selected existing nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code you have mentioned in your question solves the problem of create new revision or just update with out a new revision when a node is updated programatically in that particular instance.. It has nothing to do with form option in node edit page...

When you do `$node->revision = FALSE;`

It is just like telling to node your are updating should be saved as a new revision or not when a node is updated at that particular instance of node_save...

Use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to disable this option in node edit page form..

in your custom module implement MODULE_form_alter and check for node id's you want to disable this option..

```
$form['revision_information']['#access'] = FALSE;
```

OR

```
$form['revision_information']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: Should it be `$form['revision_information']['#disabled'] = TRUE;`? Access FALSE, but disabled is TRUE.

Comment: Yeah.. I have corrected.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are not getting the correct data in the array `$results`

Try this,

```
    $results = array();
    $results = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->fields('n',array('nid','vid'))
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAll();
    foreach ($results as $result) {
    $node = node_load($result->nid);
    // Disabling the Create new revision option
    $node->revision = FALSE;
    node_save($node);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks shrish. It got worked by using the hook_form_alter.